# Properly Zip App for Deployment to Beanstalk via Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: node.js, command-line, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

Can't zip node.js app properly in yaml file to be deployed properly by AWS Beanstalk. Looking for the proper way to structure the zip command for Beanstalk to be able to consume it properly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html

It currently deploys correctly in Beanstalk with an older version of the app zipped in the repo already as app.zip, and will zip up new commits and deploy the new changes just fine. If I remove the old app.zip file from the repo, the app doesn't deploy correctly in Beanstalk anymore. I'd like to be able to understand this behavior and how to fix it. Here's the yaml:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: "Zip File"
        script:
          - zip app.zip -r ./*
        artifacts: 
          - app.zip
    - step:
        name: "Deploy to Production"
        deployment: production
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
        - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.5
          variables:
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
            ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
            S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
            ZIP_FILE: "app.zip"
```

Comment: One step that is missing is the installation of zip. If you look at [bitbucket pipeline for beanstalk](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml) you should notice a line where call **apt-get** to install **zip**